# How do I fix a failure to build due to a "Duplicate module name" collision in a react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

`RN 0.39.2`

This may sound like a duplicate of [React-Native Packager Failure: Duplicate module name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38885760/react-native-packager-failure-duplicate-module-name) but there aren't any real fixes in there, just workarounds. There are others but they are for older versions of RN or are similar but different root causes. I have my own workaround (see below) but I'd like to actually solve the problem instead of having to do this workaround five times a day.

The error:

```
Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-native-vector-icons
  Paths: /Users/collumj/research/kishar-nine/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/kisharNine.app/package.json 
  collides with 
  /Users/collumj/research/kishar-nine/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/__fixtures__/files/package.json
```

The workaround (for me):

```
rm -rf android ios
git reset --hard
npm start
```

There must be a way to actually resolve this. Did this package not link properly? I installed it when I added in NativeBase (http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.13/getting-started).

Update: also tried unlinking the `react-native-vector-icons` library (because apparently you don't need to? unsure, the linking may be redundant in the instructions). Anyway, it didn't work, same error.

Comment: How does your yarn.lock file look ? Do you have double entry there ?

Comment: That's a big file. I can say that react-native-vector-icons doesn't appear in there at all -- but it is in my package.json. Odd.

Comment: Could be if you used the `npm` command instead of the `yarn` command. Try deleting node_modules directory. `npm cache clean` and then `yarn install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: OK this may not have actually worked, checking now...

The solution to this was to use `react-native unlink` to unlink the `react-native-vector-icons` library. I think the `native-base` library's instructions are out of date about the need to use link. Maybe? Not really sure but I can say that after unlinking I can still use icons:

```
<View style={{
    marginTop: 10,
    flexDirection: "row"
}}>
    <H3 style={{
        marginRight: 5
    }}>Icons:</H3>
    <Icon name='ios-home'/>
    <Icon name='ios-menu' style={{
        fontSize: 20,
        color: 'red'
    }}/>
</View>
```

Renders fine.

Comment: @supriya-kalghatgi please comment on this

Answer (score 0):

Could be if you used the `npm` command instead of the `yarn` command. Try deleting node_modules directory. `npm cache clean` and then `yarn install`